# Querying sequelize filtering by join table

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to filter  select by a field in join table, the only solution I found so far was an object filter from the query result

**User table**

```
    User.init(
    {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize, // Connection instance
        modelName: "User", //Model name
    }
);
```

**Company Table**

```
Company.init(
    {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        slug: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        account_expire_date: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize, // Connection instance
        modelName: "Company", //Model name
    }
);
```

**UserCompany Table**

```
UserCompany.init(
    {
        role: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize, // Connection instance
        modelName: "UserCompany", //Model name
    }
);
User.belongsToMany(Company, { through: UserCompany });
Company.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserCompany });
```

**The goal is query companies by user email with role admin**

```
const user = await User.findAll({
    where: {
        email: "guazelli.ugo@gmail.com",
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: Company,
        },
    ],
});
```

**Is there anyway to add the filter where UserCompany = admin?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add whre functiona while join the UserCompany table like;

```
   const user = await User.findAll({
        include:[{model:Company},
                {model:UserCompany, where:{role:'admin'}}],
        where: {
            email: "guazelli.ugo@gmail.com",
        } 
    });
```

Regards